# Two elements in the same line

Tags: html, css

My problem is quite simple. I have a input-group and I simply want to put the glyphicons in front of the button in a responsive way.
I tried so many things and nothing is working.

Please, help

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table columns-formating">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>IBAN</th>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="iban" class="form-control form-control-sm input-sm" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span class="color-green"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            <span class="color-red"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: _I tried so many things and nothing is working._ what you have tried?

Comment: You can use property **display:inline-block**

Comment: float: left for elements to display in same line and display: table for container

Comment: Use a pseudo element: [an example with font awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean but if you want to have your icon in same line and inside of button:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table columns-formating">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>IBAN</th>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="iban" class="form-control form-control-sm input-sm" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
             <span class="color-green"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            <span class="color-red"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></span>
            Validate</button>
            </span>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that does not working. look at the button, everything is messed up

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, your icon after validation button?

Comment: If you want to have icon after button, you can put <span> of your icons inside of input-group-btn class not inside of button

Answer (score 0):

Add `input-group-addon`

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table columns-formating">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>IBAN</th>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="iban" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="color-green"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            <span class="color-red"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></span>
            </span>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
             
            Validate</button>
            </span>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```